# Duda sobre array y punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy repasando este código que convierte las mayúsculas a minúsculas y no consigo entender por qué se declara `char*argv[]` y más tarde en el bucle for se usa `argv[1][i]` como si fuera un array de dos dimensiones.
 Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    if(argc>1) {
        int i;
        char c;
        for(i=1; (c=argv[1][i]) != '\0'; i++){
            if('A'<=c && c<='Z')
                putchar(c+'a'-'A');
            else
                putchar(c);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char*argv[]
```

Según esta declaración, `argv` es un array de cadenas de caracteres. Es decir, cada elemento de `argv` es un puntero a `char`

- argv es un array, cada elemento del array es un parámetro que se la ha pasado a la aplicación al ejecutarla. Para acceder a cada parámetro necesitas un índice
- Cada parámetro es una cadena de caracteres, luego necesitarás otro índice para acceder a una posición en concreto de dicha cadena.

Lo único que está haciendo ese código es recorrer los diferentes caracters del primer parámetro que ha recibido el programa e imprimir dicho caracter en forma de minúsculas

Answer (score 1):

Es que es un array de dos dimensiones.

Empecemos porque un array y un puntero es el mismo tipo de datos. La única diferencia es que el array ya viene "precargado" con un espacio asignado. Es decir:

```
char *puntero; 
char array[5];
```

Son dos tipos de datos **equivalentes**. Es más, si hacemos esto:

```
puntero = array;
```

Resulta que ahora, **además** apuntan ambos a los mismos datos. Es decir:

```
puntero[3] == array[3]
```

Devuelve cierto.

Visto esto, resulta que un array de dos dimensiones es un array de punteros. Es decir, si aplicamos la misma conversion a esta estructura de datos:

```
char mi_array_de_dos_dimensiones[][];
```

es sería igual que:

```
char *mi_array_de_dos_dimensiones[];
```

Flipante, no? En realidad es una forma muy económica de implementar arrays. Sencillamente te apoyas en una cosa que se llama "aritmética de punteros" que hace todo el trabajo de los arrays. Y pista. Lo increible es cuando intentas visualizar cómo queda esto en memoria.

Comment: *Son dos tipos de datos equivalentes...* No es del todo cierto. En C, un puntero y un array son tipos de datos diferentes. El estándar de C dice que cuando usas un array como *expresión* (como, por ejemplo: `puntero = array;`) [decaen](https://www.quora.com/In-C-why-do-arrays-decay-into-pointers) a puntero (es decir, el compilador realiza una conversión implicita) pero esto no quiere decir que los punteros y arrays sean lo mismo.

Comment: Efectivamente @MrDave1999, eso es así, pero creo que para el nivel de esta pregunta, la respuesta que he dado le pone en el buen camino